# Create new column based on conditions in another columns

Tags: r

I have a B2B customer dataset where we want to be able to measure the onboarding process of our customers after giving them access to our webshop. A company can have many users that has been given access. I would like to create another column called "Onboarding" with conditional to "First log-in date" that if a user from any given company has logged in for the first time, then we would classify this company or customer as onboarded with the value "Yes" otherwise "No". And this # means they have not logged in yet. I am unsure how to approach this in R. Can any help me please? ^^

An example is attached as a picture:

[image: data frame]

[data frame with new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgKEi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your data or provide the reproducible example.

Comment: `data$Onboarding <- factor(data[, "First log-in date"] == "#", labels = c("Yes", "No"))`

Comment: Almost! :) I think I also may need to group by "company". For example, company A has five users, three of them has already logged in but two of them have never logged in. But because company has three users that has already signed in, the other users that has not should also get a "Yes" to indicate that company "A" has been onboardet.

Comment: @RoseNonglakSeesanJensen I have a question `Do you mean that if any one employee has logged in out of many, the rest all should be marked as "Yes" and if not a single employee logged in then all should be marked as "No" ?? Or is there any other condition than I just mentioned?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, for a given company if all users have First-Login Date as "#", the company has not been onboarded. Is that correct?

You can use the split-apply-combine approach for such problems:

```
#### Data ####
 my_df <- data.frame(Company  = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                  UserID     = c("Simon","Hans","Jane","Alex","David","Dan","Sarah","Susan","Bob","Keith",
                              "Harry","Adam","Kenneth","Denial","Henna","John","Dylan"),
                              First_Log_in_Date = c("2018-02-22","#","2018-03-07","2018-04-29","#","#","#",
                                                    "2018-05-01","2018-02-27","2018-06-08","2018-07-12",
                                                    "2018-02-21","#","#","#","#","#"))

#### Split - Apply - Combine ####
my_df %>% split(., .$Company) %>% lapply(function(company_df) {
    # "Check if any user logged in
    if(any(company_df$First_Log_in_Date != "#")) {
        company_df$onboarded <- T
        return(company_df)
    }
    company_df$onboarded <- F
    return(company_df)
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

Comment: what if I want to add another condition. For example, when I do visualisation on companies that has been onboardet "Yes" or "T", I want column "First-Log in Date" to show the date the first user has logged in. So that when I filter for "Yes" in "Onboardet", then for company A, "First-Log in Date" should show date 22.02.2018.

Comment: You can apply the split-apply-combine approach to solve that problem as well. 1) Split data.frame on company. 2) For each split, calculate the smallest date in "First_Log_in_Date" column and append that value to a new column. 3) rbind each split data.frame into the solution data.frame. I would suggest asking a new question if you want a working solution with code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you unselect my answer as the accepted answer? I believe my solution was the first one that worked for your specific use-case. Your question also did not indicate any package-dependencies (like dplyr), so a base R solution should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you wanted...

First data for reproducible report:

```
 dat <- data.frame(Company  = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                   UserID    = c("Simon","Hans","Jane","Alex","David","Dan","Sarah","Susan","Bob","Keith",
                              "Harry","Adam","Kenneth","Denial","Henna","John","Dylan"),
                   First_Log_in_Date = c("2018-02-22","#","2018-03-07","2018-04-29","#","#","#",
                                                    "2018-05-01","2018-02-27","2018-06-08","2018-07-12",
                                                    "2018-02-21","#","#","#","#","#"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To answer your original question, I would simply use base ifelse() function:

```
dat$Onboarding <- ifelse(dat$First_Log_in_Date=="#", "NO", "YES")
```

And we get the result "Onboarding" column filled with Yes or No, depending upon the log in date.

To answer your condition based 2nd question, I would simply use "dplyr" package functions:

```
dat <- dat %>% group_by(Company) %>% 
               mutate(onborded = ifelse(n_distinct(First_Log_in_Date) > 1, "Yes", "No"))
```

We get the result "Onboarding" column filled with Yes or No, depending upon the log in date for employees, in any of the group company, is other than just "#".

The table will look like:

[image]

Comment: Almost! :) I think I also may need to group by "company". For example, company A has five users, three of them has already logged in but two of them have never logged in. But because company has three users that has already signed in, the other users that has not should also get a "Yes" to indicate that company "A" has been onboardet.

Comment: @RoseNonglakSeesanJensen I have a question `Do you mean that within a group of a company if any one employee has logged in out of many, the rest all should be marked as "Yes" and if not a single employee logged in then all should be marked as "No" under onboarding column?? Or is there any other condition than I just mentioned?`

Comment: @RoseNonglakSeesanJensen If the condition is that `"minimum of three employees should be logged in within a group company to be marked as onboarding "Yes" for all the employees, then the solution by chaos will not work"`